# Rails 3.2, activeresource and certificate authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, ssl, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeresource

I'm writing to ask for an example of use of the active resource with certificate authentication.

The documentation found on http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base does not provide examples.

I have two rails application that need to communicate: APP1 (https://app1.mauroapplications.com), APP2 (https://app2.mauroapplications.com)

I generated public/private keys for each application (RSA). APP2 has the public key of APP1 (app1.pem) and viceversa.

In my development environment I have a self signed certificate for SSL.

How do I have to configure a Model extending ActiveResource in APP2?

Many thanks in advance,

Mauro

Comment: Same problem here... Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I switched to token protected APIs (http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning and http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api)

Answer (score 4):

The following code works:

```
class Person < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = 'https://api.people.com:3000/'
  self.ssl_options = {
    cert: OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open('cert.pem')),
    key: OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.open('key.pem')),
    ca_file: 'ca.cert.pem',
    verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
  }
end
```

Where `cert.pem` is your client certificate, `key.pem` your client's private key and `ca.cert.pem` the CA certificate (for validation of the server certificate).